# How to call mysql stored procedure with where clause as in parameter using Delphi 7 ADO

Tags: mysql, delphi-7, procedure

I have a mySQL stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE `update_table_set_where_datefield`(
in p_date_time datetime)
BEGIN
  UPDATE table SET onefield = 1
  WHERE datefield = p_date_time;
END
```

I try to call the stored procedure above, using Delphi 7 ADO, but the data is not changed. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use params on AdoStoredProcedure,

ADOStoredProc1.ParamByName('PARAM').AsInteger := variable;

ADOStoredProc1.Open;

Comment: But p_date_time parameter is a datetime data type, not integer.

Comment: Why use ADOStoredProc1.Open? The mySQL stored procedure is not return a result set.

Comment: it was an example, you should use ADOStoredProc1.ParamByName('PARAM').AsDateTime, And you can try ADOStoredProc1.ExecSql;